# Titanium Facebook module not completing login on iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, titanium

I've run into a weird issue using Titanium 3.2.0.GA and the Facebook module. When I try calling fb.authorize(); and if I'm logged into Facebook through iOS 7, the dialog pops up asking if I would like to allow it to blah blah blah. But once I tap "Allow", it triggers the login event with code -1, and is unsuccessful. However, if I'm not logged into Facebook through iOS 7, and login to Facebook through Safari after calling fb.authorize();, everything works as expected and the login event is triggered successfully.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = ****;
fb.permissions = ['email'];
fb.forceDialogAuth = false;

fb.addEventListener("login", function(e) {
    if (fb.success && fb.accessToken != null) {
        console.log(fb.accessToken);
    }
});
```

And like I said above, when the Facebook button is pressed I just call `fb.authorize();`.

Is anyone else having issues like this on iOS 7 using Titanium?

Comment: Which titanium sdk you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it. On my Facebook app, I had to add an iOS app and turn the "Single Sign On" on. Facebook was having issues last night and wouldn't let me make changes to my app but I just tried it today and it works now. I think this might be something new for iOS 7, but I'm not sure. However, turning Single Sign On to On worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare All bellow variables in calling function only not globally other wise each time it will call fb.authorize().

i.e

```
var fb = null;
function facbooksharing(sharingData){
      if(fb == null){

        fb = require('facebook');
        fb.appid = "******";
        fb.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream','publish_actions'];
        fb.forceDialogAuth = true; `enter code here`
    }
        if(fb.loggedIn==true)
     {
        fb.dialog("feed", sharingData, showRequestResult);
     }else{

       fb.authorize();
     }
      function showRequestResult(e) 
    {

        if (e.success)
         {
           if (e.result)
            {
               Ti.API.info("Data Shared between your friend successfully.");
            }
        }
    }

      fb.addEventListener("login", function(e) {
      if (fb.success && fb.accessToken != null) {
            console.log(fb.accessToken);
      }
});

}
```

Let me know is this resolve your problem or not.